# Animating a Sphere Eversion (Turning a sphere inside out)

Tags: animation, topology

I'm interested in animating a sphere eversion like the one shown in the following gif.

[image]

The full video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI-To1eUtuU

Normally, I would offer my own code as a starting point, however, in this case, I'm at a loss. I can't figure out the math that generates such a transformation in a way that can be coded.  Does anyone have any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try looking at this:  https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+turn+a+sphere+inside+out&docid=608019425049924306&mid=03F4AF87377ABC80E3D803F4AF87377ABC80E3D8&view=detail&FORM=VIRE.  Then start small:  figure out how to transform just  one guide strip and two caps by pushing caps through, stop before crease, then twist caps in opposite directions.  Get just that animation working to start than build on this.  If I was doing it I would start by just drawing the guide strip and two caps as three geometric objects and call it a day.  Next day, figure out how to transform them any way.

Comment: You cannot solve such problems without knowledge of math.  I recommend you to read this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10466). They prepared all the formulas for Mathematica implementation and even give recommendations about the best choice of parameters. I suggest you type all the relevant equations from the text and ask for help if you face any problems.

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @yarchik:  Thanks!  Will work a bit on the equations in Appendix B of the reference.

Comment: @B flat:  I believe yarchik is correct about the approach to solving this problem and feel my  post below is only a distraction and deleting it may open up your thread to more review so wish to do so.  If you prefer to leave it let me know.  If not I'll remove it tomorrow morning.  The link yarchik gave is helpful and I'm making some progress on it.

Comment: @Josh I agree. Thank you!